# Visual Studio XML Documentation : Attributes

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012

This may be a simple question to people who have anything advanced with XML Documentation from Visual Studio.

I can generate the documentation for a class and members no problem, but I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to include attributes in that?

I'd like to include any property or method attributes in the documentation.

Thanks in advance,

Richard

Comment: If you mean so that it is included in your sandcastle documentation the answer is no you cant include that. Sandcastle will document it without tags. Find all supported tags here: http://www.ewoodruff.us/xmlcommentsguide/html/4268757F-CE8D-4E6D-8502-4F7F2E22DDA3.htm  however you can use any tag you like and it will be included at least in your xml file. <summary>Some summary</summary><attribute>Serializeable</attribute>

Comment: Hey, yeah I was looking for say [ChildActionOnly] to be automatically picked up, but doesn't look like that's possible?

Comment: As i said inside the Sandcastle options you have a checkbox/value for document attributes. with that set to true you should have these attributes in your documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example:

```
/// <summary>
/// The summary
/// </summary>
/// <attribute>[ChildActionOnly]</attribute>
[ChildActionOnly]
public void TheMember()
{

}
```

is valid. and you can even see it in the intellisense info.

Comment: Hi, 
Yes that's good to know, but I was looking for something more automatic than this; I don't really want to have to write all that stuff myself.

Is it possible to get the attribute automatically, or would I need to add it to the comment myself?

Comment: not to my knowledge. i tried to look what ghostdoc does, but it seems to ignore attributes for theres no proper tag. but as i said if you activate it in sandcastle you should have attributes documented without any tags. sandcastle also uses reflection to get these kinds of metadata

Comment: see top checkbox: http://i1-win.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/Sandcastle-Help-File-Builder_7.png